# Can translators(Google Translate, Deepl etc.) own the translation of just one word?

Tags: copyright, translation

I have a list of just words in English language. Can I use translations of these words to other languages in commercial?
For example Google Translate Terms of Service says that I can use their translations only for personal use.
Important notice: I'm not planning to use these services each time I want to get a translation. I'm planning to use PREtranslated words list.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead?

Comment: @phoog I need to have about 3000 words translated to more than 10 languages.

Comment: They do offer paid licenses for the service that allow commercial use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Single-Word translations are facts or uncreative

Facts are not copyrightable - See Feist v Rural. As such, 1:1 combinations might be considered facts and uncopyrightable. Further, there is no creativity in any individual word and the established one or more possible translations. Creativity only starts when the translation contains full sentences and actual expressions.

At best, the whole dictionary gets database copyright protection where it exists.

Comment: Incidentally, it is technically not true that translations are "facts", they are marginally creative creations, but this point has never been tested in court. If translations were mere facts, then every text in Language A would have exactly one translation into language B, which is manifestly untrue.

Comment: @user6726 *single words*. Think... "Guerre" - "War" - "Krieg". That triplet is a fact. But translating "La guerre ne change jamais" - "War never changes" - "Krieg verändert sich nie" shows some tiny spec of creativity, because I might have chosen different words for 'never changes' or even chosen a different word order. The creativity is in *choosing* from the list of possible translations.

Comment: @Trish "that triplet is a fact". Is it? Why is _guerre_ not _warfare_? The same creativity shown when selecting the perfect translation of a word used in a sentence is also used when attempting to translate a single word. I am not contradicting your answer, I'm sure it's legally accurate, and your main point stands, but calling the claim that every word has one exact translation a "fact" is as true as the—equally legally true—"fact" that [bumblebees are fish](https://www.theinertia.com/environment/bumblebees-are-now-classified-as-fish-by-californian-supreme-court/).

Comment: @terdon take a more simple example: The verb *etre*, the verb *to be* and the verb "sein" are the direct aequivalents in French, English and German. That is a fact. how they can perform in a full sentence is creative.

Comment: @Trish I'm sorry, but things really aren't as simple. Especially when discussing very basic components of language like the verb _be_. Just look at the number of different definitions the English and French words have. And these are very closely related languages. They happen to share many of the verb's auxiliary uses. Other languages don't go down that route. Others do, but add more complexity, like the case of Spanish with its _ser_ and _estar_, both of which would be translated as _be_ in English. But is _be_ then _ser_ or _estar_? You cannot know without knowing the context.

Comment: @terdon You **vastly** underestimate what is a fact under copyright law.

Comment: @trish I don't think they're disputing what a fact is for copyright purposes -- just your suggestion that there is no creativity in translating a single word because each word has some single, objectively correct translation, regardless of context. That's a pretty wrong characterization.

Comment: Copyright law usually requires more than a trivial amount of creativity. Another example is the copyright (or lack thereof) of security camera footage.

Comment: @bdb484 that's not what I tried to say, but that each word has a finite list of possible translations, and that list is a fact.

Comment: I think that's still incorrect, though, as there are infinite possible translations; they just involve varying degrees of creativity. I can translate *guerre*  using any of the common translations that I'll find in any dictionary, or I can translate it as "foolish French fighters, frittering foreign flesh." In American copyright law, I think that's the part that makes the difference -- not that "guerre = war" is a fact but that drawing that equivalency is insufficiently creative to trigger copyright protection.

Comment: As a linguist and not a laywer, I agree with terdon and bdb484 and would be curious if you can provide a reference. I don't dispute that the translations might be considered "facts" despite the drawbacks. But I would be interested to read about it

Answer (score 5):

A creative work is only protected in the case of a person creating that work. The individual (conventional) words of a language are not created by the author, they have existed for a very long time. The relation between words in two languages may or may not be created (recognized) by an individual – the English and French words "egg", "oeuf" refer to the same thing and that equivalence has been known for a millenium (was not created by Google). Google's method relies on massive copyright infringement without any creativity (it is the automatic product of a computer program, possibly excused under fair use), and automatic computer program outputs are not protected by law.

This is not the forum for discussing how human translations work and why they can be creative (even when selecting an appropriate translation for a single word), it is sufficient to say that when a computer program emulates the human creative process (for instance in translating the word *kutaangalaala* in an obscure language, which I would translate as "to be paralyzed in not knowing know what to do in a situation"), that relation is not "a fact" and it is creative, but it is a *relationship* and not an expression. Method patents (not copyright) protect certain kinds of "relations". I probably cannot gain copyright over the short English phrase "to be paralyzed in not knowing know what to do in a situation" (the quantum of creativity required for protection is judged on a case by case basis).

In short, translations of words and phrases are not your property because you did not create those words, they already existed, and the specific arrangements that constitute a translation (into English, for instance) of one word in a language were also not created by you, they were created by someone else. There is a tiny chance that a translation of one word could be protected when the translation is a word-sequence with null prior attestation, but not a 1-to-1 translation "egg" ←→ "oeuf".

Google's prohibition is about something else: you can only use their *software* non-commercially, but you would not be e.g. embedding Translate into a commercial web page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Sometimes it’s just seems that everything is copyrighted and you can’t use anything

Comment: "the English and French words "egg", "oeuf" refer to the same thing and that equivalence has been known for a millenium" English hasn't existed for a millennium (two n's, by the way).

Comment: @Acccumulation, the exact same word existed in Old Norse, so we can say that the English word "egg" has existed for a millennium, even though English itself hasn't, I think.  But that's perhaps a topic for [english.se].

Comment: "you can only use their software non-commercially, but you would not be e.g. embedding Translate into a commercial web page": actually you can also use the _service_ only non commercially, which includes using their API to translate text for a commercial purpose, _unless you have a suitable license, which they will be happy to sell you.